# What is the format for the new options json object server.register hapijs method

Tags: javascript, json, hapi.js

Anyone could show me what is the new format for options json object that must be passed to `server.register()` method in hapijs?

> **this is how I wrote my `server.register()` call.**

```js
server.register({
    register: require('good'),
    options: {
        opsInterval: 5000,
        reporters: [
            {
                reporter: require('good-file'),
                events: { ops: '*'},
                config: {
                    path: './logs',
                    prefix: 'hapi-process',
                    rotate: 'daily'
                }
            },
            {
                reporter: require('good-file'),
                events: { response: '*' },
                config: {
                    path: './logs',
                    prefix: 'hapi-requests',
                    rotate: 'daily'
                }
            },
            {
                reporter: require('good-file'),
                events: { error: '*' },
                config: {
                    path: './logs',
                    prefix: 'hapi-proccess',
                    rotate: 'daily'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Error: Invalid monitorOptions options child "reporters" fails because ["reporters" must be an object]
at Object.exports.assert (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
at Object.exports.register (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/good/lib/index.js:31:10)
at Object.target [as register] (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/object.js:77:34)
at each (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:318:14)
at iterate (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:36:13)
at Object.exports.serial (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:39:9)
at internals.Plugin.register (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:321:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rodrigo/Projetos/estudos/api/greetings-hapi/server.js:26:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Reporters seems to be an object not an array but how do I should write and what are your properties?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://github.com/hapijs/good you will see the reporters is an object with the keys being name of reporter and the value an array of objects with the keys module, name and args.  Read the docs here https://github.com/hapijs/good/blob/master/API.md for further info.